# How to create/plot non over-lapping nodes in NetworkX python 3x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to create the final path map for Travelling salesman problem. The code below creates the map as shown in image. I am using random layout for Digraph.Since the number of nodes is much, few nodes are overlapping, which makes the paths hard to recognize.

[image]

Code

```
map_paths_reduced = map_paths[:10]  # Choosing only first 10 paths for simplicity


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(len(edge_labels)+1))
black_edges = [edge for edge in G.edges()]
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
G.add_edges_from(map_paths_reduced)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_size=500)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=1)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=black_edges, arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, arrows=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you tried `nx.circular_layout`?

Comment: @rodgdor No, not yet. I am not aware of that layout. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Is there no pre-existing positioning for the nodes?

Comment: Yes @Joel, there is no pre existing positioning for the nodes. I think the problem is with the number of nodes i used. I couldn't find anything in their in their documentation about the maximum number of nodes to use. But anyway, if there is any function to prevent overlapping nodes in random_layout would be worth.

Comment: `random_layout` assigns the nodes to random positions in the unit square, without enforcing any distance constraints (as otherwise, they wouldn't be assigned uniformly at random).  If you need to prevent them from overlapping then change their size.  Why not try one of the other layout functions?

Comment: @rodgdor I tried. It is number of nodes i used is the problem. I tried to reduce the nodes size and label font but it doesn't seems to be good enough to recognize them.